# Two schengen visas simultaneously

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I am planning for a two years masters course in Europe. I have received an admit from Italy for which I would be applying for a visa soon. Also, I m expecting an admit from a German university, which would be more preferable for me(if I get an admit). Can I apply for both Italian and German long term student visa in a span of 15-20 days??

Comment: If you get admitted by the German university can't you just withdraw your Italian visa application?  (I agree with @pnuts by the way, so voting to close, sorry.)